# CSS up & down buttons for jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-slider

CSS, another of my obvious weaknesses, is killing me.

Poster of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732974/attach-jquery-ui-slider-to-side-of-div-as-divs-scrollbar) was generous enough to show me how to append a slider to a div, but I think I need up and down buttons since my scrollbar could have a ton of steps.

I won't embarrass myself or bore you with all of my iterations that came out plain wrong.

Could someone show me how to append a jQuery UI icon on top and bottom of the vertical slider to make it look like a scrollbar so that it works with the CSS provided in the post above?  It's the CSS that's not working for me.

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Great answers, thank-you very much.  Is there a way to keep the slider from bleeding into the buttons?  I'll try to put up the check asap.

Nevermind.  Just figured out what top and bottom really do.

**Final Conclusion**

Both solutions work, and I was able to adjust for bleeding with top and bottom easily.

I gave the checkmark to Abody97 because of the backwards compatibility, so I guess it sounds like tomaroo will be more correct in the future.  Too bad stack doesn't allow for multiple checkboxes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my try: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/P3dAp/).

What I basically did: first, I modified the HTML a bit:

```
<div id="vertical-slider">
<div class = "up">/\</div>
<div class = "down">\/</div>
</div>
```

Added this to CSS:

```
#vertical-slider {
    position: relative; /*necessary for the buttons' positioning to work*/
}
.up {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /*up there*/
    left: 0; /*on the left*/
}
.down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /*down there*/
    left: 0; /*on the left*/
}
.up, .down {
    width: 100%; /*take up all the width inside the slider*/
    background: rgb(0, 162, 232); /*prettiness*/
    color: white; /*prettiness, too*/
    z-index: 1000; /*make sure they're not covered*/
}
```

Note that you'll have to handle clicks yourself, but this should give you an idea on how to achieve the visual layout.

Comment: You CSS peeps have my envy and astonishment.  Thank-you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudoselectors:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Fpxv/)

You'll want to play with the `top` and `z-index` properties to get the desired look.

```
#vertical-slider:before{
    content: url('/slidertop.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#vertical-slider:after{
    content: url('/sliderbottom.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: 192px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, he could use `:before` and `:after`, except that browser support for those isn't so nice (well, at least not in IE <= 7). Plus, it's only a couple of lines in HTML; not *too* much to save.

Comment: also perfect.  i'll need to test to see which one is best for checkmark.  Thank-you very much!